# Bind service class with generic

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have one interface with generic

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface GenericInterface<T> {

    Optional<T> doSmth(long Id);
}
```

I have two implement classes, for instance GenericInterfaceImpl and GenericInterfaceImplImpl, they both are using own class as a generic in one method

```
public class GenericInterfaceImpl
    implements GenericInterface<OwnClass> {
}

public class GenericInterfaceImplImpl
    implements GenericInterface<OwnClass2> {
}
```

I have another two classes, that which should use dependencies of above services

```
public class Class1 {
private final GenericInterface<OwnClass> gen;
@Inject
public Class1(GenericInterface<OwnClass> gen) {
this.gen = gen;
}
}

public class Class2 {
private final GenericInterface<OwnClass2> gen2;
@Inject
public Class2(GenericInterface<OwnClass2> gen2) {
this.gen2 = gen2;
}
}
```

> ServiceBinder class

```
bind(GenericInterfaceImpl.class).to(GenericInterface.class);
bind(GenericInterfaceImplImpl.class).to(GenericInterface.class);
```

After running application, assuming, that I have registered ServiceBinder, I've got this error

```
Caused by: org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=GenericInterface,parent=Class1 etc.)
```

How to bind it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 8 hours of searching, I've found solution

```
   bind(GenericInterfaceImpl.class).to(new TypeLiteral<GenericInterface<OwnClass>>() {});
   bind(GenericInterfaceImplImpl.class).to(new TypeLiteral<GenericInterface<OwnClass2>>(){});
```